# global significance of glm model

Tags: statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test

I am a beginner regarding GLMs and R. I have built the following glm model:
`glmodel <- glm(CPUE ~ Précip + Temp + Vent + Sal + Prod + NAO + AMO + PO4, family = "Gamma"(link = "log"), data= octopus_data)`. I used the "summ" function from "jtools" package and i got this output in which there is this chi-square test:

> MODEL FIT:
> χ²(8) = 13.20, p = 0.00
> Pseudo-R² (Cragg-Uhler) = 0.27
> Pseudo-R² (McFadden) = 0.02
> AIC = 4325.78, BIC = 4362.68

From what I understand it's a global significance test of the model, and the value 13.20 is the observed value of chi-square with 8 degrees of freedom.
So I compared the observed value to the one in the chi-square table (15.51, α=0.05) --> I shouldn't reject the null hypothesis (H0: βk = 0 with k (1, 2, …, 8)). on the other hand, the p-value < 0.05 hence, I should reject the null hypothesis.
So my questions are :

1. Is my understanding correct in the first place?
2. If yes, is my model significant or not?

I forgot to mention that there are some coefficients that are significant.
Any help would be very appreciated.